# APACHE httpd.conf error

Tags: apache-2.2, connection, xampp, localhost, internet

I have recently installed the latest Apache.

It is working fine through `localhost:80` and through `10.0.0.51:80`, but I can't connect through `[External IP]:80`.

I have forwarded ports correctly, but I don't know if it has something to do with the httpd.conf file.

So here is a link to my [httpd.conf file](http://www.mediafire.com/?3ajurmwktp6fk95).

Comment: Are you behind a firewall or a NAT device?

Comment: No. I just believe there is something to do with the http.conf file

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that your apache is listening on every address:

   - get this in your conf:

     ```
     Listen 0.0.0.0:80
     ```
   - check it from console:

     ```
     $ netstat -luntp | grep :80
     ```
   - I would change ServerName to the IP (I'm not an expert, but I think it gives better results with external IPs):

     ```
     ServerName localhost:80
     ```
2. Then, visit the internal ip of the server 10.0.0.51:80 and ensure it's showing ok.
3. Now, ensure that you are redirecting the ports correctly, and check it visiting your external IP address outside your network (with a phone, o similar, so your router/firewall doesn't get in the way out) and

   - if the browser says connection interrupted, it's probably a firewall issue
   - if the browser is waiting too long, could be a firewall issue, or something in your apache configuration.